# how to derive an object within the same array of objects using common key

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a collection like this

```js
let data = [ 
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f"
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2"
    type: "Downtime"
    usageInHours: 5.3
    usageInMinutes: 330 
  },
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f"
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2"
    type: "Uptime"
    usageInHours: 14.3
    usageInMinutes: 870
  }
];
```

I want something like this

```js
data = [
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f"
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2",
    Uptime: 14.3,
    Downtime: 5.3
  }
];
```

I need to create/modify an object by using existing objects on the same array, with few values to become as keys, their key value is another property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
let data = [
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f",
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2",
    type: "Downtime",
    usageInHours: 5.3,
    usageInMinutes: 330,
  },
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f",
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2",
    type: "Uptime",
    usageInHours: 14.3,
    usageInMinutes: 870,
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { instrumentId, instrumentName, type, usageInHours } = curr;
  const isExist = acc.find((o) => o.instrumentId === instrumentId);
  if (isExist) {
    isExist[type] = usageInHours;
  } else {
    acc.push({ instrumentId, instrumentName, [type]: usageInHours });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [ 
  {
    instrumentId: "a5f",
    instrumentName: "Instrument 2",
    type: "Downtime",
    usageInHours: 5.3,
    usageInMinutes: 330 ,
  },
  {
   instrumentId: "a5f",
   instrumentName: "Instrument 2",
   type: "Uptime",
   usageInHours: 14.3,
   usageInMinutes: 870,
  }
];

let result = [];

data.forEach(({instrumentId, instrumentName, type, usageInHours}) => {
  const transformedObject = {instrumentId, instrumentName, [type]: usageInHours};
  const index = result.findIndex(({instrumentId: existingId}) => existingId === instrumentId);
  
  if (index === -1) result.push(transformedObject);
  else result[index] = {...result[index], ...transformedObject};
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works like charm..Thank you